# Filter some divs by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I really want to do is to filter some divs by a h1 inside it
here will be some products and an input field.
I need jquery compare between the value from the user and h1 of the div
then if h1 doesn't contain the value of input field
the div which has "remove" class and id "mYY" should be "display:none"

And here is my code below:-

```
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search For Components" />

      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div id="mYY" class="remove col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <form>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="back">
                          <div class="des">
                              <h4>DESCRIPTION :</h4>
                              <p>some info of the product</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <h1>some product</h1>
                      <p class="price">125.00</p>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
           </div>
```

And this is the js code below:-

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, div, name, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("mYY");
    name = div.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
         name[i].getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
        if (name.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            div[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            div[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where have you defined `ul`?

Comment: sorry 
edited
i am sure this code is wrong just want to tell you what i need

Comment: use "style.display = 'block' " instead of empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery code:

On change of the #search field it checks if there are any H1s that do not contain that text and hides their .remove element.

```
$('#search').change(function(){
    var searchVal = $(this).val();
    // Hide the fields that do not contain the seached value
    var $foundH1 = $("H1:not(:contains("+searchVal+"))");
    if ($foundH1.length) {
        $foundH1.closest('.remove').hide();
    }
    // Show the fields that do contain the seached value
    var $otherH1 = $("H1:contains("+searchVal+")");
    if ($otherH1.length) {
        $otherH1.closest('.remove').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This could also be a "keyup" event rather than change, or any other event you like I guess!

Comment: This work !
but only one time i can search 
if i tried to search more all products disappeared

Comment: Awesome!

So to fix that issue you can add :

Comment: var $otherH1 = $("H1:contains("+searchVal+")");
    if ($otherH1.length) {
        $otherH1.closest('.remove').show();
    }

Comment: i just want the result appear even it lowercase or uppercase
could you help me with this ?